# Arrayformula with IF + AND Statements

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I am trying to show the status of each contract by using IF + AND Statements for each row. We set the status of the contracts to "Active," "Expiring (when it is 30 days out)," and "Expired." These statuses are used to trigger automations using Zapier.

I thought I could simply add an ARRAYFORMULA to calculate each row automtacially, however, I am finding out it does not work in this case.

[Here is a spreadsheet with a example of what I am trying to accomplish](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1B1dfmNfk8rIAGolzheTdzr6ctJZ2T9lHYHp1t59Tkgo/edit#gid=1854013385)

Is there a workaround I can apply that will calculate the IF statements for each row with having to copy/drag each formula down the column? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Within arrayformula use:

`*` for `AND`

`+` for `OR`

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(if(len(B8:B20)*len(C8:C20)*len(D8:D20),if((B8:B20>=C8:C20)*(B8:B20<=D8:D20), "Expiring", IF(B8:B20 > C8:C20, "Active", "Expired")),))
```

[image]